# How does the digikam quality sorter work?

Tags: image-quality, digikam

I'm trying to use the digikam quality sorter but I don't know how it works. The documentation I found that most looks like a tutorial is an almost 1-year old [unaswered question on the digikam user mailing list](https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/digikam-users/2014-December/020509.html). Has anyone ever succeeded in making it work, and if so written a small tutorial?

Comment: I have tried applying image quality sorter in Digikam 5.6.0 completely according to the instructions. The application seems to occupy lots of PC time but I have not seen any result from the process. As kind of test I created separate directory with only four images of proven poor quality. The application ran for ten minutes and produced no visible results. If it does what it pretends to do it would be a wonderful addition to the Digikam arsenal of applications. Michel Klerk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Image Quality Sorter Tool, you can use it like this: 



*The Image Quality Sorter assigns quality labels to images according to the settings in*

```
Settings → Configure digiKam... → Image Quality Sorter.
```

There you also have to enable this tool if you want to use it. Since it is a time consuming process it's a good idea to check Work on all processor cores and restrict the job to certain albums or tags. The tool will set the red flag for “rejected”, the yellow one for “pending” and the green one for “accepted”.

Regarding the tutorial, you can find them here:

I found the documentation at the following link  https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-graphics/digikam/index.html

and also a tutorial at the following link: 

https://userbase.kde.org/Digikam/Tutorials

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have enabled it and looked into your sources, but nothing happens. I have no idea how to invoke this tool, despite about half an hour of search and research.

Comment: see https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/digikam-users/2021-August/032648.html Forget for the moment this feature. A student work this summer to rewrite
all algorithms with better results and more. This will be integrated in
digiKam 7.5.0 if all is fine, while this winter